# Insecure File Upload on WebApps

Tags: web-application, malware, php

I found a website where I can upload any file I want. Now what are the biggest threats for them if they didn't install PHP (so a php shell can be uploaded, but it won't execute)? I found no sign of ASP either.

Comment: is the upload is in cdn or at the document root or server root?

Answer (score 2):

You only give a limited amount of information about the system, so I can only give a broad answer. A good source for orientation is the current [ASVS](https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/raw/master/4.0/OWASP%20Application%20Security%20Verification%20Standard%204.0-en.pdf) (Version 4.0.1). In chapter "V12: File and Resources Verification Requirements" we can find requirements for file uploads that point us in the right direction. I've selected some of those requirements and added an explanation to apply it to your scenario:

- 12.1.1 Verify that the application will not accept large files that could fill up storage or cause a denial of service attack.
- 12.1.2 Verify that compressed files are checked for "zip bombs" - small input files that will decompress into huge files thus
  exhausting file storage limits.
- 12.1.3 Verify that a file size quota and maximum number of files per user is enforced to ensure that a single user cannot fill up the storage with too many files, or excessively large files.

These requirements are mainly about **denial of service attacks** by flooding the application with files until it runs out of storage capacity. If the target system doesn't protect against such attacks, this might be an important risk to address.

- 12.2.1 Verify that files obtained from untrusted sources are validated to be of expected type based on the file's content.

There are many reasons for that, but in general, you have to check if the file is used in a way, where **a wrong file type can cause damage to the system**. Without knowing the details of the application, I can only guess if that's the case.

- 12.3.1 Verify that user-submitted filename metadata is not used directly with system or
  framework file and URL API to protect against path traversal.
- 12.3.2 Verify that user-submitted filename metadata is validated or ignored to prevent
  the disclosure, creation, updating or removal of local files (LFI).
- 12.3.3 Verify that user-submitted filename metadata is validated or ignored to prevent
  the disclosure or execution of remote files (RFI), which may also lead to SSRF.
- 12.3.4 Verify that the application protects against reflective file download (RFD) by validating or ignoring user-submitted filenames in a JSON, JSONP, or URL parameter, the response Content-Type header should be set to text/plain, and the Content-Disposition header should have a fixed filename.
- 12.3.5 Verify that untrusted file metadata is not used directly with system API or
  libraries, to protect against OS command injection.

Path traversal means **breaking out of the current location and write to other locations**. This might enable an attack to **write over an existing file** or **place executable code where it either gets executed by the system or can be executed by the attacker**. If that's possible, that can be a severe risk. The other points are going in a similar direction. The basic idea is, if an attacker can manipulate the meta-data in a malicious way, different attacks are possible. **Command execution** would be one of the most severe risks. If any of those apply to the actual system, must be verified.

- 12.4.1 Verify that files obtained from untrusted sources are stored outside the web
  root, with limited permissions, preferably with strong validation.
- 12.4.2 Verify that files obtained from untrusted sources are scanned by antivirus
  scanners to prevent upload of known malicious content.
- 12.5.2 Verify that direct requests to uploaded files will never be executed as
  HTML/JavaScript content.

Storing the files in the web root may allow an attacker to **execute the file directly** or simply **use the application to serve malicious content to others** (e.g. to do **drive-by infections**, **perform XSS against to domain**). A malware scanner is able to identify such malicious files, if the pattern is known to be dangerous. If those safety nets are not present in the applications, the attacks described can be a risk.

Those is a broad field of potential attacks. Which of them actually apply to the application you are testing, must be verified. If you have the chance to do the audit white box, you should be able to verify all of those potential risks based on the source code and the server config. If you have to do it black box, some of them might be tricky to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can upload any file does not mean that the upload is insecure. As long as the files are stored so that they can not be included as code by the application or executed otherwise (i.e. special directory, no post processing ....) it can well be secure. It might even be intentional that everything can be uploaded - you can do this with Dropbox or web based mail agents etc too.

> Now what are the biggest threats for them ...

This is impossible to say with the only information that anything can be uploaded. It is absolutely unclear with this lack of information what should intentionally happen and what might unintentionally happen with the uploaded files. Thus the range of problems might be from no problem at all up to will cause a nuclear strike.